# Maven unable to find packages in jar

Tags: maven

I have two projects.  Project A has Project B as a dependency in it's pom.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.package.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Project B's pom:

```
<groupId>my.package.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>abc-common</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

However, when I attempt to build Project A with Maven (via eclipse using arguments "clean install -X"), I get compilation errors:

```
[ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\package\abc\client\Myclass.java:[3,37] error: package my.package.abc.common.client does not exist
```

I get package * does not exist errors for literally every package from Project B.  I checked the local Maven repo, and the jar is present and inside the jar the compiled files are there.  According to the debug output, Project B is successfully added to the classpath when starting to compile Project A.

```
[DEBUG] Classpath:
...
[DEBUG]  ...\.m2\repository\my\package\abc\abc-common\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\abc-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So, if Maven is finding Project B, and Project B does have all the classes inside it that it's supposed to, why is it unable to find any of those classes during the compilation phase?

EDIT:
The total output from "clean install -X" on Project A is too big, so this is a larger but still abridged version.

```
    [INFO] Deleting directory ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes\my\package
    [INFO] Deleting directory ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes\my
    [INFO] Deleting directory ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes\gov
    [INFO] Deleting directory ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes
    [INFO] Deleting directory ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ abc-bci-web ---
    [DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3:
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
    [DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
    [DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.0-beta-4:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.4:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13:compile
    [DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3
    [DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3
    [DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
    [DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7
    [DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
    [DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.0-beta-4
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.4
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1
    [DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3d882ea9]
    [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources' with basic configurator -->
    [DEBUG]   (f) buildFilters = []
    [DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
    [DEBUG]   (f) escapeWindowsPaths = true
    [DEBUG]   (s) includeEmptyDirs = false
    [DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes
    [DEBUG]   (s) overwrite = false
    [DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: my.package.abc:abc-bci-web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\pom.xml
    [DEBUG]   (s) resources = [Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: true, FileSet {directory: ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\resources, PatternSet [includes: {**/*}, excludes: {}]}}]
    [DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@71f15b67
    [DEBUG]   (f) useBuildFilters = true
    [DEBUG]   (s) useDefaultDelimiters = true
    [DEBUG] -- end configuration --
    ...
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [DEBUG] resource with targetPath null
    directory ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\resources
    excludes []
    includes [**/*]
    [DEBUG] ignoreDelta true
    [INFO] Copying 5 resources
    [DEBUG] file applicationContext.xml has a filtered file extension
    [DEBUG] filering ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\resources\my\package\abc\server\config\applicationContext.xml to ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes\my\package\abc\server\config\applicationContext.xml
    [DEBUG] file log4j-at-info.xml has a filtered file extension
    [DEBUG] filering ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\resources\log4j-at-info.xml to ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes\log4j-at-info.xml
    [DEBUG] file log4j-debug.xml has a filtered file extension
    [DEBUG] filering ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\resources\log4j-debug.xml to ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes\log4j-debug.xml
    [DEBUG] file log4j-info.xml has a filtered file extension
    [DEBUG] filering ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\resources\log4j-info.xml to ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes\log4j-info.xml
    [DEBUG] file SystemSettings.properties has a filtered file extension
    [DEBUG] filering ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\resources\SystemSettings.properties to ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes\SystemSettings.properties
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) @ abc-bci-web ---
    [DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.1:
    [DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
    [DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
    [DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:1.8:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:1.8:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:1.8:runtime
    [DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1
    [DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1
    [DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
    [DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.1
    [DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7
    [DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:1.8
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:1.8
    [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:1.8
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6
    [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0
    [DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3d882ea9]
    [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile' with basic configurator -->
    [DEBUG]   (f) basedir = ..\workspace\abc-bci-web
    [DEBUG]   (f) buildDirectory = ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target
    [DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes, ..\.m2\repository\my\dps\frameworks\dps-gwt-framework\2.13-SNAPSHOT\dps-gwt-framework-2.13-SNAPSHOT.jar, ..\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar, ..\.m2\repository\com\allen-sauer\gwt\log\gwt-log\3.1.8\gwt-log-3.1.8.jar, ..\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, ..\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar, 
...
..\.m2\repository\my\package\abc\abc-domain\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\abc-domain-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, ..\.m2\repository\my\package\abc\abc-common\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\abc-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]
    [DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\java]
    [DEBUG]   (f) compilerArgument = -implicit:none
    [DEBUG]   (f) compilerId = javac
    [DEBUG]   (f) debug = true
    [DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
    [DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
    [DEBUG]   (f) fork = false
    [DEBUG]   (f) generatedSourcesDirectory = ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\generated-sources\annotations
    [DEBUG]   (f) optimize = false
    [DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes
    [DEBUG]   (f) outputFileName = abc-bci-web
    [DEBUG]   (f) projectArtifact = my.package.abc:abc-bci-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@71f15b67
    [DEBUG]   (f) showDeprecation = false
    [DEBUG]   (f) showWarnings = false
    [DEBUG]   (f) source = 1.6
    [DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
    [DEBUG]   (f) target = 1.6
    [DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
    [DEBUG] -- end configuration --
    [DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
    [DEBUG] Source directories: [..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\java]
    [DEBUG] Classpath: [..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes
     ..\.m2\repository\my\dps\frameworks\dps-gwt-framework\2.13-SNAPSHOT\dps-gwt-framework-2.13-SNAPSHOT.jar
     ..\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar
     ..\.m2\repository\com\allen-sauer\gwt\log\gwt-log\3.1.8\gwt-log-3.1.8.jar
     ..\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
     ..\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar
     ...
     ..\.m2\repository\my\package\abc\abc-domain\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\abc-domain-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
     ..\.m2\repository\my\package\abc\abc-common\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\abc-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]
    [DEBUG] Output directory: ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes
    [DEBUG] Classpath:
    [DEBUG]  ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes
    [DEBUG]  ..\.m2\repository\my\dps\frameworks\dps-gwt-framework\2.13-SNAPSHOT\dps-gwt-framework-2.13-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [DEBUG]  ..\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar
    [DEBUG]  ..\.m2\repository\com\allen-sauer\gwt\log\gwt-log\3.1.8\gwt-log-3.1.8.jar
    [DEBUG]  ..\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
    [DEBUG]  ..\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar
    ...
    [DEBUG]  ..\.m2\repository\my\package\abc\abc-domain\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\abc-domain-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [DEBUG]  ..\.m2\repository\my\package\abc\abc-common\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\abc-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [DEBUG] Source roots:
    [DEBUG]  ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\java
    [DEBUG] Command line options:
    [DEBUG] -d ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes -classpath ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes;..\.m2\repository\my\dps\frameworks\dps-gwt-framework\2.13-SNAPSHOT\dps-gwt-framework-2.13-SNAPSHOT.jar;..\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.4.0\gwt-user-2.4.0.jar;..\.m2\repository\com\allen-sauer\gwt\log\gwt-log\3.1.8\gwt-log-3.1.8.jar;..\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;..\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;..\.m2\repository\my\package\abc\abc-domain\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\abc-domain-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;..\.m2\repository\my\package\abc\abc-common\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\abc-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar; -sourcepath ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\src\main\java; C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\ch\ChDetailEntryPanel.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\sww\SwwDetailCell.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\sww\SwwDetailEntryPanel.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\sww\SwwReviewTab.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\ReviewComposite.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\juvenile\JuvReviewTab.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\ch\ChDetailCell.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\sww\SwwNameList.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMenuPanel.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\events\NameSelectionChangeEvent.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\sww\SwwDetailCellList.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\ReviewTabController.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\ReviewMenuPanel.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\ch\ChReviewTab.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\ch\ChNameList.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\ncic\NcicReviewTab.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\fbi\FbiReviewTab.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\events\NameSelectionChangeHandler.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\ch\ChDetailCellList.java C:...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\review\ReviewTabHandler.java -s ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\generated-sources\annotations -g -nowarn -target 1.6 -source 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 -implicit:none
    [INFO] Compiling 22 source files to ..\workspace\abc-bci-web\target\classes
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java:[3,37] error: package my.package.abc.common.client does not exist

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java:[4,52] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.view.incidents does not exist

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java:[5,37] error: package my.package.abc.common.shared does not exist

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java:[6,51] error: package my.package.abc.common.shared.authorization does not exist

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java:[17,31] error: cannot find symbol

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[3,44] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.events does not exist

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[4,44] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.events does not exist

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[5,44] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.events does not exist

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[6,44] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.events does not exist

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[7,49] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.view.header does not exist

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[17,47] error: type BaseMainPanel does not take parameters

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[17,75] error: cannot find symbol

    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[17,103] error: cannot find symbol
    ...

    [INFO] 100 errors 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 32.497s
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 19 13:20:24 MDT 2012
    [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/123M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project abc-bci-web: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java:[3,37] error: package my.package.abc.common.client does not exist
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java:[4,52] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.view.incidents does not exist
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java:[5,37] error: package my.package.abc.common.shared does not exist
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java:[6,51] error: package my.package.abc.common.shared.authorization does not exist
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcBciWeb.java:[17,31] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[3,44] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.events does not exist
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[4,44] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.events does not exist
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[5,44] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.events does not exist
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[6,44] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.events does not exist
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[7,49] error: package my.package.abc.common.client.view.header does not exist
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[17,47] error: type BaseMainPanel does not take parameters
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[17,75] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] ...\src\main\java\my\packge\abc\client\AbcMainPanel.java:[17,103] error: cannot find symbol
    ...
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project abc-bci-web: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: I would take a look at your jar file (jar tf .m2\repository\my\package\abc\abc-common\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\abc-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar). Maybe the config of project B is incorrect?

Comment: If all the classes are in there in the right folders, what could be wrong with the config?

Comment: Can you post the entire output from Maven when you `clean install -X`?

Comment: Question updated with output of Project A.

Comment: I suppose project A and project B are not being aggregated in another pom file right? Maven will ignore the repo and use the module if that's the case. That is, of course, on the long shot case that your module is different from the artifact in the repo

Comment: Nope, no aggregation being done - Project A is the end application.

Comment: Just saving some work to others, [here](http://pastebin.com/5JQMVqa2) 's a pastebin copy of the output so you can see it without wrapping

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped. If what @AleksanderBlomskøld said doesn't help, I don't know what could be wrong. Just double check there's .class files there, no typos on the directories, wrong capitalizations, `my` is on the root of the jar, etc...

Comment: Have you cleaned and re-installed B just before A ? Maybe the version of B that is in the repo is a very old one... Since B is just a dependency for A, not a module, you can not expect maven to build B every time you ask him to build A (maybe you aware of that, just asking).

Comment: @Yanflea Yes, I've cleaned and installed B, I've even tried changing the version around.  Always the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: @Miquel What's crazy is it GWT compiles fine, so eclipse is able to understand the maven reference and access the project no problem, so all the package stuff is fine.

Comment: I take it you are using jar packaging through all, right?

Comment: Project B is jar packaged, Project A is war.

Comment: If A would be war i would have said you missed to give the type in your dependency of B but you described it the other way around. But one thing is interesting, cause it seemed to me that some of the missing classes are compiled in the pastebin output.

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake in the name of your package in project B (my.packge.abc => my.package.abc)

Comment: The package names are fake - I can't use the real ones on here, so my find/replace was poor.

Comment: @John, Do you get the same error when doing `mvn clean install` on project A from command-line.

Answer (score 1):

did you do a successful "mvn clean install" on project b first?

since project a has a dependency on b that build must go first and the .jar file must be in your local repository.

If it works in eclipse you may just have configured the classpath using eclipse project dependencies which does not influence how maven works.

Answer (score 1):

are you doing all of that from the command line? I suggest you to wipe all your artitacts from Maven's cache (the ~/.m2/repository) and re{clean, install} project B then A.
Maybe the version in the cache is buggy. Did you try

```
jar tvf [your jar]
```

to check what's in there?

Maybe you used two maven binaries with two different cache directory. Typically an eclipse maven build (with plugin's maven) and a command line maven build (external binary).

Comment: I was doing it all from eclipse, but I manually removed the items from the cache and also opened up the built jar manually to see inside.

Comment: And in eclipse, the A project has no compilation error? Also be sure to have nothing in project's build path but JRE and Maven dependecies. In a first time i would be great to "sync" eclipse and maven (say, the same problem for both) to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that project B is not build yet (the snapshot version doesn't exist jet), or is out of date.

so if you first do a clean install on project B and then a clean install on project A it should run as expected.

I would recommend to make a project with a child projects A and B, then the parent project will build both projects

Answer (score 0):

This was one of the top hits when I was searching for answers to the exact same scenario. Unfortunately, no answer appeared in the thread.

It took a lot of wrangling, but in my case the pom.xml for project B (the dependency) was copying the .java files into the .jar instead of the .class files. Changing the resources section in the pom.xml accordingly gave a clean build and run.